# Block diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

It is known that any real skew-symmetric matrix is similar to the block diagonal matrix of the form
$$M(\Lambda)=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    J_1 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & J_n
  \end{pmatrix}$$
where each bloc is a skew-symmetric matrix $J_i=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
  0 & -\lambda_i\\
  \lambda_i & \phantom{-}0
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\Lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

See for example:
[Skew-symmetric matrix](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Skew-symmetric_matrix)

> **Question:** Starting from $M(\Lambda)$, what are the change of orthonormal basis that do not break the property of $M(\Lambda)$ being a block diagonal matrix?

> **Attempt:** Let $O=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq 2n}$ be a real orthogonal matrix. Then $OM(\Lambda)O^t$ is a block diagonal matrix if and only if for all $i\geq j+2$, $1\leq j\leq 2n-2$,
> $$\lambda_1(a_{i2}a_{j1}-a_{i1}a_{j2})+\ldots+\lambda_n(a_{i,2n}a_{j,2n-1}-a_{i,2n-1}a_{j,2n})=0,$$
> i.e. the $(n-1)(2n-1)$ vectors
> $$v_{ij}=\big((a_{i2}a_{j1}-a_{i1}a_{j2}),\ldots,(a_{i,2n}a_{j,2n-1}-a_{i,2n-1}a_{j,2n})\big)$$
> are orthogonal to $\Lambda$, so their rank at most $(2n-1)$. Note taht any two distinct lines $L_i$ and $L_j$ of $O$ are of rank $2$ so at least one of the components of $v_{ij}$ is non zero.
> For $n=2$,
> $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
> \lambda_1(a_{11}a_{32}-a_{12}a_{31})+\lambda_2(a_{13}a_{34}-a_{14}a_{33})&=&0\\
> \lambda_1(a_{11}a_{42}-a_{12}a_{41})+\lambda_2(a_{13}a_{44}-a_{14}a_{43})&=&0\\
> \lambda_1(a_{21}a_{42}-a_{22}a_{41})+\lambda_2(a_{23}a_{44}-a_{24}a_{43})&=&0
> \end{array}\right.$$
> Here $v_{13},v_{14},v_{24}$ are proportional to $(-\lambda_2,\lambda_1)$
> How to proceed further and characterize these orthogonal matrices?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user Are you looking for matrices $O$ such that this holds for all matrices $M(\alpha)$, or are you looking for a way to get this set such that $OM(\alpha)O^t = M(\hat \alpha)$ holds for a specific $\alpha$?

Comment: @user56980 Also, note that users are discouraged from either asking *or answering* questions that provide insufficient context, particularly where it is not clear that the asker has put an effort into answering the question before asking it. It would be helpful if you would [edit] your question to give us some idea of what you've tried so far. For instance, have you thought about the problem for $n = 2$? Have you thought about what the solution would look like for $OM(\alpha)O^t = M(\alpha)$?

Comment: Also, do you want the whole set of such matrices or a subset would be also useful?

Comment: @KBS I want the whole set of such matrices and 'not only' the permutations of plans

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after two observations.

For $n=1$,
$$OM(\lambda)O^t=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
M(\lambda), & \text{if}\ \det O=1,\\
M(-\lambda), & \text{if}\ \det O=-1.
\end{array}\right.$$
Since $OM(\lambda)O^t$ and $M(\Lambda)$ have the same characteristic polynomial $P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n(X^2+\lambda_i^2)$, then $OM(\lambda)O^t$ is a block diagonal matrix if and only if
$$OM(\lambda)O^t=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \pm J_{\sigma(1)} & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & \pm J_{\sigma(n)}
  \end{pmatrix},$$
for some permutation $\sigma\in S_n$. So the 'admissible' change of orthonormal basis are exactly the product of the two matrices:
$$  \begin{pmatrix}
    O_1 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & O_n
  \end{pmatrix},\ O_1,\ldots,O_n\in\mathrm{O}(2)$$
and $M_\sigma$, the matrix of the permutation of the plans $P_i=\mathrm{Span}\{e_{2i-1},e_{2i}\}$ to $P_{\sigma(i)}=\mathrm{Span}\{e_{2\sigma(i)-1},e_{2\sigma(i)}\}$.